# HTML5 Audio behavior

Tags: javascript, android, html, webkit, html5-audio

I have an audio element in a HTML5 page. I start playing the audio and then pause it. After that I go back to homescreen by pressing home button and make a phone call. When the call ends, audio element resumes automatically. This happens on Android 4.0.3

The problem is that, this is not the expected and desired behavior. Unfortunately, When browser is running in background, javascript events are not thrown and I can't catch and prevent this behavior using Javascript.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using on android?

Comment: Actually this is the desired behaviour, it happens on even basic nokia  symbian based mobile phone where suppose you listen to a song, you get a call in between, then the song resume from where you left on, these devices don't even support multitasking but this feature is there everywhere.

Comment: yes, but i have paused the audio. if it starts automatically by itself, it should not be the expected behavior

Comment: I'm seeing this too, even on ICS. As @MehmetSerdarBiçer says, it happens when the audio tag was previously paused. I'll have to try putting a check in, when ontimeupdate event happens, to see if it's happening.

Comment: This is very weird. The play event doesn't fire when it resumes playing and even setting audio src to null and destroying the audio element, it will keep playing. Maybe for 30 seconds until it stops. Or just keeps going. I even ran a timer to continuously force audio to pause and it kept un-pausing itself. This is all after a phone call.

Comment: Test case: http://jsbin.com/welcome/5289

Comment: Bug on jelly bean too. Seems like a browser bug which basically calls native onPause and resume events for handling the users pause of the HTML5 audio session. I suppose a good way to handle would be to not pause the audio but to terminate the session when user pauses the audio. Store the value at which the audio was pause and terminated. then on play use a custom event to restart the audio from that instant. I don't know how you could do something like this but this is my best guess! HTH

Comment: @Shouvik I was under the impression Android Browser isn't on Jellybean. Is this happening on Chrome? I've contemplated the workaround you mention, but the problem is seeking to some point can be extremely slow, as the player often needs to load the whole track up to that point (depends on server settings, which can't be controlled if streaming third-party tracks).

Comment: I am running stock android and android browser comes with it, though it might be here because I upgraded from ICS. I have not check it on chrome. Will do and tell you if its present here too.. As for loading the entire track goes, how about caching the content on local storage?

Comment: hmm, okay that will be an issue with third party tracks. So I am lost on a solution. I think your best bet would be to raise a bug request and wait for them to get to it and resolve it!

Comment: Okay, issue did not present itself in chrome. So this def a default android browser issue.. HTH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have an ICS phone to try it out, but here is what I would do:

`pause` obviously keeps track of the audio time position. 
4.0 seems to automatically resume where you paused the audio file

So instead of pausing you could `stop` your audio file.
Unfortunately, `stop` isn't supported by HTML5.

You have a tricky solution:

- `pause` audio
- store the position: `trackPos = myTrack.currentTime;`
- store volume: `trackVol = myTrack.volume;`
- mute it: `myTrack.volume = 0;`

Then when the user comes back and hits play again:

**if trackPos exists**

- set the starting position to trackPos: `myTrack.currentTime = trackPos;`
- `play`
- `mytrack.volume = trackVol;`
- `delete window.trackPos;`

This is tricky but should work if you are using JavaScript controls.

If you use native controls though play and pause would be managed by the browser's interface. Then you should just store the position and start getting REAL dirty:

- remove the sources:

  myTrack.removeChid( yourSRCs )
- restore your SRCs and position on focus
- wait for the user to play

That's a quick and dirty draft, not tested. But it should work

**///EDIT///**

A working Javascript demo, at least on my desktop. Try it on your ICS:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCfeG/)

(save the file, I guess you can't launch jsfiddle properly on a phone)

Comment: This all makes sense in theory, but I tried doing something like this and it just resumed and kept playing for at least another 30 seconds. I didn't try setting volume to zero though. But I did set audio src and audio to null, which should have wiped it altogether! I want to believe, but I'd really need to see a working demo of this to do so unfortunately.

Comment: if you can do with JavaScript controls I can set you up a quick demo

Comment: Thanks for the demo. It doesn't work on Android Browser, however. Playback doesn't start.

Comment: @mahemoff in fact it doesn't work on my ICS tablet. I figured out it's because I hotlinked the audio from jPlayer's server. I tried with a file hosted on mine though and it plays without issue. So playback should work if you replace the audio with your files.

Comment: In my case, I'm streaming 3rd party content.

Comment: @mahemoff It should work with 3rd party, my example didn't work with jPlayer's files because I don't have any permission to hotlink to their servers. The solution is right though. Test it with local files first then if it works it should work with your 3rd party sources. SRC isn't the issue in your case

Comment: Unless it's actually tested, it's unlikely to work, because there are lots of things that work in theory, but not with the Android browser.

Comment: actually this logic, with a combination of answer of @say2joe, seems to be the only solution to this case. but instead of setting volume = 0, I set source to empty and reverted back. because volume is not changeable (at least in mobile browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a script block. It should work.

```
var ppAudio = function(event){
    var ppMethod = (event.type == "blur")? "pause" : "play",
        audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio"),
        l = audio.length;
    for (;l--;) audio[l][ppMethod]();
};

// window.onfocus = ppAudio;
window.onblur = ppAudio;
```

You don't need the onfocus event, I suppose. But, its here for an example of toggling.

Comment: The problems I've seen are practical problems with the shoddy Android browser implementation. Unless this code is tested on Android browser, it's not likely to work.

Comment: Agreed -- the Audio API (and Video) is not very good on the Android browser. I'm not sure whether or not switching to a different app will trigger a blur event, but the code I wrote is standards-based and will work across most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could declare a boolean to keep track wheter you paused manually or not, so you could evaluate it on focus or another proper event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the audio object from the DOM and restoring it on play?

Answer (score 0):

I'd attach a 'onFocus' event to the  with a boolean switch to determine the previous state of the audio player, if you get the focus with a previous 'paused' state then stop the player, or else play it.